# How do you add a folder to a project in Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2012 for Web?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-express

I have a folder that contains my JavaScript project.  I want to make a project in Visual Studio and include my project.

I created a "Blank Solution" project since there's no JavaScript type.  Now, how do I add the folder with all my JavaScript in it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Browse to the folder your javascript files are in, and drag that folder into your blank solution's Solution Explorer, or right click in the Solution Explorer on the right and hit "Add > Existing Website", then browse to the folder your javascript files are in.

Comment: The second solution works.  The drag and drop does not work for me.