# Html+css+javascript development with Visual Studio

Tags: javascript, html, css, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

My main experience with developing in Visual Studio is as c#/c++ developer. But now I need to create html+css+javascript front end for [probably] PHP code, and I've heard that Visual Studio has pretty nice capabilities in that range, including debugging javascript.

However, I can't find anywhere a "web" project (except for the ASP.Net stuff, which I'm not sure that it is the right thing).

Here's what I think I need to do:

1. Create html file
2. Create css file
3. Include a bunch of javascript libraries
4. Write my own javascript code
5. Press F5 and debug the code in different browsers.

I'm mainly interested in intellisense,  not a visual editor.

Is Visual Studio the right IDE for this kind of web development? And if it is, how do I set up the kind of project I described above?

Comment: Any text editor will do for this. Personally, I love [Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/2).

Comment: actually, I've tried Sublime with c++, but I never got it to load functions from referenced files

Comment: I have no experience of using it with c++ (which i guess requires a more full-featured IDE) but HTML/CSS/JS need nothing more complicated than Notepad. Sublime just add bells and whistles.

Comment: Try [aptana](http://www.aptana.com/) it's really good for this sort of thing. It's a great IDE which lets you code in a number of different languages.

Comment: Visual Studio can edit all kinds of web files (including the intellisense and syntax highlighting stuff), but yes, it's geared towards ASP.NET, with basically C# and VB.NET as the only server side languages. So if you're going to do PHP, it might not be the most appropriate tool. There is [this Microsoft page](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6eb51f05-ef01-4513-ac83-4c5f50c95fb5) but I don't know anything about that.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think the instructions at [How do you add a folder to a project in Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2012 for Web?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17750087/how-do-you-add-a-folder-to-a-project-in-microsoft-visula-studio-express-2012-for) might work for setting up a Visual Studio project:

1) New blank solution
2) Right click on the solution and select Add existing website
3) Browse and select the folder with your html, css, javascript, etc. files
4) Right click on the page you want it to start on and select set as start page

As for running against different websites, you might try a Visual Studio extension.  A decent starting list is here: http://www.asp.net/mobile/device-simulators

Comment: Looks good. Do you maybe have some experience with debugging javascript files while running the website from Visual Studio on which you can elaborate? It asked to add a Web.config file because that was needed for debugging. But it doesn't hit the breakpoints I put in the *.js files.